# How do I get the variable names in an overloaded object in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, object, overloading, document-oriented-db

I'm using Overloading with PHP, and what I want to do is;
When I'm calling the object, it would look like this.

```
$obj->person->name->function();
```

To do so, I use __get and __call functions. They would look something like this:

```
function __get($field){
    return $this;
}
```

However, I want to know the variable names of person and name, since that can change
whenever. I tried to do like this:

```
function __get($field){
    $array[] = $field;
    return new object($array);
}
```

They get saved, but as I add another line, it just adds it to the array. It does not
clean up after a function was called. I tried to empty the array at __call, but that
didn't help. I wanted to Google this, but so far.. I'm out of luck.

**Is there a native function for this in PHP?**

> -- TOO MUCH TO READ? STOP HERE, THE REST IS JUST MORE EXPLANATION --

However the __call sends the array and sends you to another class that handles
functions that is real.

**The reason:**
I have a 5 programmers that are used to the mongoDB-class, and we're changing
a large codebase from MongoDB to another DB. With this fix we would be able to change
the whole codebase's DB at once, without much hassle of building query's instead. We just
do the query's in the functions class. (access when __call is called). However, a typical
line for a DB query looks like this today:

```
$this->db->accounts->update(<array>);
```

This line connects to the one database, inside that database it connects to accounts.
However, we have some "special" variables, like $core. It looks like this:

```
$this->db->core->accounts->update(<array>);
```

That one does not connect to the same database.

What we need is to be able to build a line of objects inside objects, that is dynamic. It needs to find what the names called are, so we can put these in querys. Only for ONE line, not all of them. Its basicly a document-based infrastructure on a key-based database, with a lot of hacking. :-D

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a different object while accessing the property.

```
class TempObj{
  public $table;

  public $db;

  public function __call($name,$arguments){
    switch($name){
      case "update":
        $this->db->query("UPDATE ......");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

In your `DB` class

```
public function __get($name){
  $obj = new TempObj;
  $obj->table = $name;
  $obj->db =& $this;
  return $obj;
}
```

This way when you do `$this->db->accounts` it will return you the object which can handle the `__call` method for this overloaded property.

Comment: The problem with that is that accounts is also dynamic. So, it could also be `$this->db->google->accounts->update(<array>)`. I use `__call`  for that now.

Comment: What does that `accounts` signify? I believe that is for the table

Comment: Yes, that's for the table. So in the function we need to know what is. If its `accounts`, we need a variable that says it's `accounts`, if its `google` we need a variable that says it's `google`. And the call can be as long as it wants. example: `$this->db->whatever->whenever->dowhatever->when->function->says->hello()`. We need to pass `whatever` , `whenever` , `dowhatever` , `when` , `function`, `says` to the hello() function, basicly. The only variable that stays the same is $this->db.

Comment: Ok so for that you need to make an intermediary class for which you implement the `__call()` method overload. I am updating my answer for that.

Comment: Should the `TempObj` call back to the `DB` class, or back to the `TempObj`. In the end, the `hello()` function in my example should have all the names from the line. How would that work?

Comment: You could save the reference back to your db class. See my updated answer.